# Multiple Web Applications - Same VM vs Multiple VMs

Tags: nginx, virtualbox

Firstly, I am more of a dev than admin. I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488098/multiple-web-applications-same-machine). But please let me know if there is a better place to ask this question.

Here's my situation. I have an application that is built to run on linux. It serves both https (on port 443 using nginx) and ssh (on port 22). But due to organizational restrictions, I am forced to run it on a windows host with a linux guest using virtual box. Also, there is another web application on the host box; both these web applications should be served based on the URL (example: app1.com, app2.com). URLs need to be preserved. All ssh traffic can default to guest.

> One idea I have to make this work is below, and I would like to know
> if I am making this more complicated than it should be. Any help is appreciated.

**Steps:**

1. Use an unused port for https (say 8443) on my host and redirect all
   traffic to the guest. Use NAT based port forwarding (8443 -> 443, 22 -> 22)
   in Virtualbox.
2. The only thing left would be to setup another nginx on
   the host as a reverse proxy.  Set up virtual hosts on windows
   (/etc/hosts) and have the two IP and URL entries (app1.com and app2.com).
   Use a separate nginx on the host as a reverse proxy to redirect app1 traffic
   to the web app on the host and app2 traffic to 8443.

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Can I avoid the extra nginx reverse proxy on the host while preserving the  URL?
> 2. Also what about ssl. Can I just set up https on the host and route it to port 80 on guest and avoid having two certs? Note: I am using NAT in Virtualbox, so there should not be any security issues I guess.

Comment: Are you restricted to using NAT in virtualbox?  If you can use bridged networking, the VM will get it's own IP and you won't need to play any forwarding games at all.

Comment: Well,whatever I try needs to be approved by a team. I can try bridged networking. Just to be prepared to answer why I am doing what I am doing, is it better than port forwarding or is it just another option. Provisioning an extra IP isn't a big cost I guess, but just in case - can you throw some light on pros and cons if any?

Comment: The most significant pro is that by using bridged networking, a unique IP is provisioned to the VM, so you don't need to fiddle with port forwarding from the host at all, and the VM hostname should be look like a fully accessible machine from the network.  This could also be a con, though, as it will mean you may need to restrict some ports on the VM using iptables.  In general, I've found that using bridged networking on VMs greatly simplifies what is needed to get applications on the VM accessible from the network.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your responses. I think one of the reasons why they wanted us to use the Windows VM in the first place was because they didn't want to deal with the additional security, admin and firewall issues with the new VM. So I will probably go with NAT and use nginx as a reverse proxy, unless someone else has any other ideas.

Comment: The guest VM will have a different IP from the host.  I would keep it simple and put the guest on the same network as the host and let DNS handle the name to IP translation.  Then you handle all services on their normal ports.  Actually I think billq said the same basic thing.  Oh, and don't forget about addressing security, admin and firewall issues on the Linux host.  If Linux were perfectly secure, MS would be out of business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered by Nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) or any Nginx [tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/). Nginx will bind to any required port, using SNI it will send requests for the different domains to different server blocks / upstream apps using [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) ([example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)). Just define a server block in Nginx for each domain.

If you want SSL try my [tutorial on Let's Encrypt](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/), but the apps have to be publicly accessible. for that.

To answer your questions.

1. A single Nginx instance should be sufficient. It can listen on any port for domain specific requests, and pass requests to any port.
2. Yes.

Example config below.

```
server {
  server_name app1.com;
  listen 80; // add other listeners required 
  location {
    // Insert proxy_pass and related statements
  }
}

server {
  server_name app2.com;
  listen 80; // add other listeners required 
  location {
    // Insert proxy_pass and related statements
  }
}

// Example of forwarding
server {
  server_name www.app1.com;
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://app1.com$request_uri;
}

// Example of SSL
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name app1.com;

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/privkey;

  // Insert a location here and remove the 301 to server on SSL
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This what I have in place currently. I have self signed certs on the test box, and will possibly use letsencrypt when it's all ready.

Comment: I guess I can't even upvote your answer for now; I will do it when I can in the future.

Comment: I think you can accept the answer, though you might have to wait a day for it. Not entirely sure how new users are limited.

Comment: Ok, I found out I need to get to 15 pts before I can upvote.